# Skips focus to readonly cells in DataGridView. But readonly false cells become true when add one if condidtion

Tags: c#, datagridview

Below code work as expected for me so far which skips readonly cells in datagridview.

```
private void dataGridViewDetails_CellEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
 {
      if (dataGridViewDetails.CurrentRow != null &&
          dataGridViewDetails.CurrentRow.Cells[e.ColumnIndex].ReadOnly)
      {
          SendKeys.Send("{tab}");
      }
 }
```

But when I add one more "if (dataGridViewDetails.ReadOnly)" condition results all "readonly = true" cells become "readonly = false" and able to edit my readonly cells.

```
  private void dataGridViewDetails_CellEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

        if (dataGridViewDetails.ReadOnly)
            return;

        if (dataGridViewDetails.CurrentRow != null &&
            dataGridViewDetails.CurrentRow.Cells[e.ColumnIndex].ReadOnly)
        {
            SendKeys.Send("{tab}");
        }
    }
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: What does `if (dataGridViewDetails.ReadOnly)` evaluate to, `True` or `False`? If `False`, are you then saying that `dataGridViewDetails.CurrentRow.Cells[e.ColumnIndex].ReadOnly` now always evaluates to `False` also?

Comment: @OhBeWise Yes, sometimes the entire dataGridView will be readonly. That time I don't want to check in cell level. Actual result I want to achieve is avoid focus to readonly cells in the datagridview.

Comment: I can't reproduce. There must be something else going on in your code. What you have shown us does not change any readonly properties!